# Group by 2 mintues mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

### Mysql Table:

[image]

I want to take sum of acceleCount for 2 minutes intervals.

### Query:

```
select  time div 120000 as TwoMinutes,                 
sum(acceleCount) as Sum
from acceleTable
group by time div 120000
```

### Result:

[image]

Here the twoMinutes column timestamp is meaning less. I want it to have a timestamp which is within the considering two minutes.

Any thoughts on how to change the sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring the timestamps to a common denominator by dividing, rounding and multiplying:

```
SELECT
(ROUND(time / 120) * 120),
sum(acceleCount)
FROM acceleTable
GROUP BY (ROUND(time / 120) * 120)
```

Comment: It works! thanks btw in my case it should be (ROUND(time / 120000) * 120000)

Comment: 1 minute = 60 seconds, 2 minutes 120 seconds was my thought. Ah your timestamp is saved in milliseconds, ok, then it's 120000 :-)

Answer (score 1):

A little optimized way to do it

```
SELECT    (ROUND(time / 120000) * 120000)  AS timekey, sum(acceleCount)
FROM       acceleTable
GROUP BY   timekey
```